# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while downloading file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to download file at my android device. This is my code:

```
InputStream in = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;

try {
    URL link = new URL(fileURL);
    in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int n, bytesBuffered = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
        bytesBuffered += n;
        out.write(buf, 0, n);
        if (bytesBuffered >1048576) {
            bytesBuffered = 0;
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
    fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    fos.write(response);
    return true;

} catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
} finally {
//closing streams
}
```

It fails at `out.write(buf, 0, n);` with out of memory error. What is wrong? I've read I'm able to set bigger heap size at manifest, but I don't find it a good solution. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the size of the file you are reading?

Comment: maybe you need to add `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest!

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve here? Just read a file - you really need to make sure the heap size is larger than the file in order to do so, however - often you don't really need to store the entire file to get an answer to some question about it.

Comment: You don't need ByteArrayOutputStream, just read InputStream and write to FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your goal is to write the content on a file, there is no need to read the content in memory before writing it.

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
    bytesBuffered += n;
    fos.write(buf, 0, n);
}
fos.flush();
```

and I would also add a `finally` clause to the try block to close fos. The finally block is call either if you return successfully or if an error occurs. This way you will not leak the `FileOutputStream`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong!

Open your `FileOutputStream` and just read from the input and copy it to the output stream:

```
private static final int BUFSIZE = 8096;

//

final byte[] buf = new byte[BUFSIZE];

int nrBytes;

while ((nrBytes = in.read(buf)) != -1)
    out.write(buf, 0, nrBytes);
```

(note: closing descriptors not handled here, left as an exercise; but sicne this is Android and you therefore don't have try-with-resource or even JSR 203, I suggest you use Guava and its [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html))

Answer (score 0):

You need a do instead of a while loop :

```
do {    
    n = in.read(buf); 
    bytesBuffered += n;
    out.write(buf, 0, n);
    if (bytesBuffered >1048576) {
        bytesBuffered = 0;
        out.flush();
    }
} while (n != -1)
```

and also add a finally block as pointed out by tony